# Consolidating Field Resets in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have the following code that I would like to consolidate:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#client_name').focus(function(){
        $('#client_name').val('');
        $('#client_email').val('');
        $('#client_address').val('');
        $('#client_city').val('');
        $('#client_state').val('');
        $('#client_notes').val('');
        $('#client_zip').val('');
        $('#client_phone').val('');
        $('#client_contact_select').val('');
        $('#contact_email').val('');
        $('#contact_address').val('');
        $('#contact_city').val('');
        $('#contact_state').val('');
        $('#contact_notes').val('');
        $('#contact_zip').val('');
        $('#contact_phone').val('');
    });
});
```

I have tried to add the ID's to an array and use a for loop to run through each one, but get no results.

What loop should I use?

Comment: Are those input fields? Maybe add the same class to all of them, and target the class once instead of each id.

Answer (score 1):

use a css class for all fields. than in jquery:

```
$('.yourClassName').val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a parent you can find the children relative to the parent

```
$("#someParent").find("input").val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```
  var ids= ['client_name', 'client_email','client_address',  'client_city' ,  'client_state' ,  'client_notes' ,  'client_zip',  'client_phone' ,  'client_contact_select' ,  'contact_email' ,  'contact_address' ,  'contact_city' ,  'contact_state' ,  'contact_notes' ,  'contact_zip' ,  'contact_phone'];

jQuery.each( ids, function( i, id ) {
  $("#" +  id).val('');
});
```

I think the foreach is good loop for doing this.